# c# rich text editor (newsletter system) for winforms

Tags: winforms, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to find a rich text editor which i can use in c#, but not on a server.. i want to use it locally..

I'm making a newsletter "system" for a client and I think that besides me making the header and the footer, the easiest way for him to input the content is via RTE... I would create it on his web server, but it only supports PHP, and I don't know PHP...

So is there a RTE (preferably open source) for visual studio c# winforms?

Comment: um your question is quite vague but I was wondering if its about just having a newsletter system why don't you install Joomla and one of its many newsletter extensions in your client's webserver?

Comment: Now, is this is a desktop application or a web application?  I see you have specified WinForms but what is this server/client business? Why would you deploy a WinForms application in a web server? Please add more details to the question and make it more clear :)

Comment: the thing is, it needs to be done in a couple of days, and i need to find the best way to make it work using what i know... the easiest way would be to make an asp.net newsletter system on the server, but since the server does not support asp.net (only php) i'm trying to find the best solution there is... joomla is not a bad idea, haven't tought of that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few Rich Text controls i found

http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/products/dotnet/overview/  http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Rich_Editor  http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Rich_Editor/  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/8723eaa1-3e0f-4cd7-a44e-f92e168fe367

All of the above i believe will help you on the job but I am very sure they are not free.

The free ones i could come up with doesn't look very appealing.

This is actually a web browser control used in Edit Mode
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/editor_in_windows_forms.aspx

Another one from code project
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/eRichTextBox.aspx

So unless you want to pay, i suggest you should least create something simple using PHP + a JavaScript based Rich Text Editor.